# Why does [].push([]) return 1?

Tags: javascript

Why does this return 1?

```
[].push([]); // outputs 1
```

Comment: because `.push()` returns new length of array. You can try `[].push([],[],[])` to make sure

Comment: A better question would be "what does the `push` method return". To which the answer is "an integer representing the new length".

Comment: Read [reference first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), then ask. Especially if you are really curious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.push()` returns the new length of the array.

```
['one'].push('two'); // returns 2 (array length is 2)
['one', 'two'].push('something'); // returns 3 (array length is 3)
```

In your case:

```
[].push([]); // array length is 1 where you get array within array. [[]]
```